# Can't Install Ubuntu 20.04 on Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, 20.04

I am attempting to run a virtual box with Ubuntu on it. I downloaded the 64 bit desktop image from Ubuntu and launch a Linux Ubuntu operating system in Virtual Box (added desktop image in the settings).

Each time I 'Start' the new machine, I am unable to fully install Ubuntu. Errors are either before or after checking disk, with a different message (or no message) occurring each time.

I uploaded the log from the most recent crash in this google drive link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1p7NiBgCKPgsUA7sjKlJSCXwz5KFQskLn

Any help to pinpoint the problem is greatly appreciated.

Intel Virtual Technology is enabled in Bios. I am running on Windows 10 but do not have Hyper-V.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be very much Ubuntu related. This must be some VB bug on Windows. I installed 20.04 on Uubntu host with no problems.

Comment: How much RAM did you allocate for the virtual machine?

Comment: @Pilot6 : log shows 3xCPUs & 7.5Gb for guest

Comment: I have tried different RAM & Hard Drive allocations. For different combinations I still yield errors and ultimately a crash before installation (note: the crash occurs at differing times with altering error messages and logs).

Comment: Do you have Docker installed with Hyper-V enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue, and I know you asked for help solving the problem (I'd like that too), but while debugging I found that I had no problem installing older versions of Ubuntu.

As a workaround I would therefor propose installing Ubuntu 18.04, then upgrading to 20.04 from there. This is what I did:

```sh
$ sudo apt update -y && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

*Updates all of your packages*

```sh
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

*Upgrades to the latest version of Ubuntu*

```sh
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

*Displays the Ubuntu version*

---

Tip: If you need several VMs running 20.04, you can duplicate the VM you just made.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I ended up cleaning the disc on my local Windows Operating System. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems lika a bug of some kind.
On Mac it worked with unchecking "Enable Audio"

Original post:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609077/how-to-fix-virtualbox-vm-quit-unexpectedly-when-running-my-ubuntu-20-04-lts-vm

Comment: How is this answer at all related the question that was asked?  The question has nothing to do with MacOS X or audio/sound.  This answer needs more explanation.

Comment: In clear text. Try with unchecking "Enable Audio" setting in virtual box. Had similar problem and that worked for me. Had a link to the original post that explained this. The author asked: "Any help to pinpoint the problem is greatly appreciated."
A thing that would take seconds to try and no harm. The symptom for me was also not being able to install correctly. Hopefully it will help someone out who "Can't Install Ubuntu 20.04 on Virtual Box"